# How to implement compressed sensing reconstruction?

Tags: matlab, compressive-sensing

I am new to the field of Compressive Sensing. I'm trying to implement an example in [this](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/magic-reconstruction-compressed-sensing.html) link. This example have described and implemented a sample tone reconstruction carefully, but unfortunately, there is no use of `l1-magic` toolbox to reconstruct the signal using compressive sensing minimization.

I know that `l1eq_pd` function in `l1-magic` calculates x in Ax=b for compressed sensing but when I use this function it returns an error `Error using linsolve: Matrix must be positive definite`.

Have anyone solved this minimization before?

Does anyone know any substitute for this toolbox?

How can I format my code in stack exchange (below code) for Matlab using `<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->` ?

---

Appendix 1:

My Matlab code:

```
%% signal initialization

n = 1/40000:1/40000:1/8;
f = sin(1394*pi*n) + sin(3266*pi*n);

%% Random Sampling

% b = Phi * f    (random sampling)
% c = Psi * f    where Psi = IDCT (sparsifying)

m = floor(rand(1,500)*length(f));
b = f(m);       % random samples of (f)
c = idct(f);    % sparsed (f)
plot(f,'b');hold
plot(m,b,'k.');title('Original Signal(f) and random sampless(b)');
axis([1,1000,-3,3])
legend('Original Signal','Randomly Sampled Signal')
figure, plot(c), axis([0,650,-10,10]);title('Sparse samples (c = IDCT(f))');

% f = Psi * c
% Psi = DCT
% f = DCT(c)
% c = IDCT(f)

%% solution 1 (x)

% Ax = b
% x = A\b

D = dct(eye(length(n),length(n)));
A = D(m,:);
% sound(f)
x = (A\b')';
b_hat = dct(x);
% sound(b_hat)

%% solution 2 (y)

% Ay = b
% y = pinv(A) * b

y = (pinv(A)*b')';
figure,plot(y),axis([0,650,-10,10])
figure,plot(dct(y)),axis([1,1000,-1.5,1.5])

%% solution 3 (s1)

s1 = l1eq_pd(y',A,A',b',5e-3,20); % L1-magic toolbox
```

This piece of code is a good example to understand compressed sensing and works correctly except the last line I am questioning.

Comment: I do not get it, in which part of your code you're using l1magic?

Comment: @MimSaad in the last line which I commented `L1-magic`

Comment: My bad!, now I guess my answer would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had encountered this problem before. In using l1-magic toolbox, the first thing you need to do is to modify the file `l1eq_pd.m`.

To do so find all `linsolve` instructions and remove the third parameter, for example on line 141 change the following line from

```
[dv,hcond] = linsolve(H11p, w1p,opts);
```

to,

```
[dv,hcond] = linsolve(H11p, w1p);
```

> This is because the structure opts specify the property of the matrix
>   A in solving Ax=b linear system of equations and omitting the
>   structure opts in the linsolve function will allow Matlab to choose
>   the appropriate solver automatically [[Reference]](http://compsens.eecs.umich.edu/sensing_tutorial.php)

If the errors persists, your own code should be scrutinized.

I suggest to have a look on [this examples codes](http://compsens.eecs.umich.edu/files/sparse_in_frequency.m).

Comment: There is a problem using those arguments, `Not enough input arguments.`

Comment: same error as my code above happens in the example you suggested

Comment: it is because the l1eq_pd.m still is unmodified